# making a transparent activity in android

Tags: android

How do you make floating activity in android which lets the focus pass through it? i made a transparent layout with two text views and a transparent theme in manifest.

```
    getWindow().addFlags(
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

this is working as expected, however, i want the device hardawre back button to function as well as show my activity on top of every screen. my hardware buttons stop working when i have my floating activity up

I want it on top of every screen like a screen filter app

Comment: I hope this is not possible, since it would introduce major security flaws

Comment: right now, this is "introducing major security flaws" by freezing the hardware controls and i want to fix this :D

Comment: Only one activity can be visible to the user at a time

Answer (score 0):

Use this theme in manifest to make Activity transparent

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score -1):

this was simple, just had to call back programmatically

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```